# prevent program from influencing terminal?

Tags: terminal

Some program started in a large script is doing `stty -echo`. I'm not sure which program it is so I have to try to find it by trial and error. Is `</dev/null 2>&1 | tee /dev/null` sufficient to block programs from accessing the terminal, or is there another way to get access to the terminal?

Actually I was unable to determine which program accesses the terminal (attempts to `strace` the entire script produced a 17MB file without `tcsetattr`, so I assume the terminal modifications are just writes of control characters). The problem was also non-deterministic; it was sometimes interfering with the terminal and sometimes not.

Placing the following prelude in the script <del>seemed to stop interference with the terminal</del> doesn't fix the problem. However, it's not clear why it doesn't fix the problem: are processes still accessing the terminal through `/dev/tty`, or are escape codes written by the programs still being dumped to the terminal by `cat`.

```
MKTEMP="$(mktemp)"
mkfifo "$MKTEMP".fifo
(
  set +o xtrace
  cat "$MKTEMP".fifo
  rm -f "$MKTEMP".fifo "$MKTEMP"
) </dev/null 2>&1 &
exec 1>"$MKTEMP".fifo
exec 2>&1
exec 0</dev/null
```

Comment: Close voters, mind explaining why this is such a bad question?

Comment: Fiddling with IO redirection is way off in the Y land of a XY problem. Why not use `strace` or `sysdig` to find out what is running `stty` or otherwise making relevant system calls (e.g. `tcsetattr`)?

Comment: Any program can open `/dev/tty` and do what it wants to do with it. See `man 4 tty`. Use thrig's recommendation.

Comment: @AlexP `man 4 tty` indicates `TIOCNOTTY` can be used to detach from the tty, after which open of `/dev/tty` will fail. Is there a wrapper program that does this? It sounds like a good idea for non-ncurses batch scripts that shouldn't be doing strange things to the terminal.

Comment: The point is that you must find out what program does what in your script. Use bisecting, use `strace`, or read the script. And TIOCNOTTY applies to the procees which calls it, not to the shell. You can also try to enter blindly <Enter>`reset`<Enter> after the script terminates. Or open another terminal and watch the processes. Seriously, use thrig's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Dilemma solved. The problem was a backgrounded `sudo -g` asking for the password on the terminal even though the current account has no password. This seems to be a bug in `sudo`; it shouldn't ask for a password if the account has no password (and it doesn't when changing users, it only does it when changing groups):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u nobody ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -g nogroup ls
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

The workaround was to add `NOPASSWD:` to `sudoers`, which made the problem go away.

The non-determinism was due to `sudo` eventually allowing the command the next time you pressed `enter` on the terminal, and not asking for a password again for some time.